# Are rem and em converted to px by browser while rendering?

Tags: css

When we use em/rem are we not giving the browser extra work to do in terms of changing the values em/rem values to px while rendering which may not be a good practice as it is many a times said that css should not contain any processing ??

Comment: If you don't want the browser to process CSS, don't write CSS.

Comment: by processing here I meant that any mathematical equations

Comment: Yeah. The browser needs to process your CSS so it can apply it to the page. So if you don't want it to do that, then don't write CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are giving the browser extra work to do. In the overall scheme of things, that doesn't matter. The browser does that and all manner of other processing for its living.